# DRF: Retrieve outer input data from nested serializer validate method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working with Django-Rest-Framework's serializers. I have two serializers one nested with the other.

```
class NestedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    value = AttributeValueField(required=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)

class OuterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    info = serializers.CharField()
    nested = NestedSerializer()
```

In order to validate the nested serializer's data I need to retrieve input data from the parent serializer, something like this:

```
class NestedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...
   def validate(self, data):
       # of course, it doesn't work, but thats the idea.
       info = self.parent.info
       # then validate the NestedSerializer with info.
```

I can't find any way to get access to those input data from the validate method. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 6):

Before `validate()` method, DRF serializers call `to_internal_value(self, data)`. You will get all data of parent serializer there. So as you defined `validate()` method in serializer, define `to_internal_value()` method and catch parent serializer's data.

Comment: Please provide a suitable example in your answer.

Comment: I have solved it as simply as implementing this method
`def to_internal_value(self, data): self.initial_data = data`

Answer (score 2):

You can access `initial_data` on the parent serializer from the nested serializers `validate()` method.  I've also added some code for using the parent fields `run_validation()` method, which would validate and return the internal value from `to_internal_value()`, which might be a better than dealing with the initial data.

```
class NestedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

   def validate(self, data):
       # Retrieve the initial data, perhaps this is all you need.
       parent_initial_data = self.parent.initial_data
       info = parent_initial_data.get("info", None)

       # Get the corresponding field and use `run_validation` or `to_internal_value` if needed
       if info:
           info_field = self.parent.fields["info"]
           info = info_field.run_validation(info)
           # info = info_field.to_internal_value(info)  # If you don't want validation, but do want the internal value

       # Do your thing
       return data
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `self.root.instance` to get the parent instance in a nested serializer.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the best idea to do it this way, `NestedSerializer` should not be aware of the parent object. It would make your code difficult to maintain, also it would make NestedSerializer dependent on OuterSerializer.

Instead, define a `validate(self, data)` method in the `OuterSerializer` and run the mutual validation there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm doing now but I'm interested to see other answers..

Basically I've created a custom field for the field in the parent serializer that needs to be accessed in the child serializer - in this case "customer". Then override `to_internal_value()` to add the field's validated data as an attribute on the parent serializer.

Once it's been added as an attribute it can be accessed on the child serializer through `self.parent.<attribute_name>` or on child serializer fields by `self.root.<attribute_name>`

```
class CustomerField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # Set the parent serializer's `customer` attribute to the validated
        # Customer object.
        ret = super().to_internal_value(data)
        self.parent.customer = ret
        return ret

class DebitField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    default_related_name = {
        'OnAccount': 'onaccounts',
        'Order': 'orders'
    }

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Method must be overridden so the `queryset` argument is not required.
        return super().get_queryset()

    def set_queryset_from_context(self, model_name):
        # Override the queryset depending on the model name.
        queryset = self.default_related_name[model_name]
        self.queryset = getattr(self.parent.customer, queryset)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # Get the model from the `debit_type` and the object id from `debit`
        # then validate that the object exists in the related queryset.
        debit_type = data.pop('debit_type')
        self.set_queryset_from_context(debit_type)
        super().to_internal_value(data)

class PaymentLineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    debit = DebitField()

    class Meta:
        model = PaymentLine
        fields = (
            'id',
            'payment',
            'debit_type',
            'debit',  # GenericForeignKey
            'amount',
        )

    def to_internal_value(self, data, *args):
        data['debit'] = {
            'debit': data.pop('debit'),
            'debit_type': data.pop('debit_type'),
        }
        ret = super().to_internal_value(data)
        return ret

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['debit'] = instance.debit._meta.object_name
        return data

class PaymentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = CustomerField(queryset=Customer.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Payment
        fields = (
            'id',
            'customer',
            'method',
            'type',
            'date',
            'num_ref',
            'comment',
            'amount',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.customer = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['lines'] = PaymentLineSerializer(
            context=self.context,
            many=True,
            write_only=True,
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there!!!
Use **`self.parent.initial_data`** to access the data given to the parent serializer.

```
class NestedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    value = AttributeValueField(required=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        the_input_data = self.parent.initial_data
        info = the_input_data['info']  # this will not be the "validated data
        # do something with your "info"
        return attrs
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not hardcode the field_name

```
self.parent.initial_data[self.field_name]
```